# Testing Material UI's AutoComplete with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai, enzyme, jestjs

I've been writing jest tests for my React application and I've run into a problem.

I have this component called AutocompleteDropdown that serves as a wrapper around a Material UI component called [AutoComplete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete).

I need a test that simulates a click on the component and then checks to make sure the dropdown list was rendered. The issue here is that the list is appended to the document's main body element instead of the component itself. I'm having trouble figuring out how to check the body for a new list.

I'm using a shallow render, so maybe I need to render an entire document with body tags and then check there? I'm not sure how to go about this because I am very new to testing in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
const chai = require('chai')
const expect = chai.expect

import { AutocompleteDropdown } from './AutocompleteDropdown'
import { apps } from "constants/testData"

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('Reporting component', () => {
  const component = shallow( 
    <AutocompleteDropdown
      list={ apps }
    /> 
  )

  it('Component should generate list when clicked', () => {
    component.simulate("click")

    // Somehow check for generated list?

  })

})
```

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? I'm having the same issue with the Select control.

Comment: Also curious if you were able to find a fix? I've also read that we're unable access the renderOutput/ renderOptions DOM updates.

 I tried simulating an event on my autocomplet input using simulate("change"), but I can't tell if I structured my object right, and if items are truly being selected from the dropdown. 

That being said, you can check that the options for your list are what you'd expect. Other suggestions included using fireEvent and react-testing-lib

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try something like

```
component.find('<.className> or <#id> or <element>').simulate('click')
```

Some additional links:

https://medium.com/netscape/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9

https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html